# How to make sure that a big amount of data from a database has been transferred in a new one

Tags: php, sql, database, data-structures, mapping

Hello i am new here and would like to join the stackoverflow community. My Question is how i could make sure that all my data from a database are correctly transferred into a new database. In my case there are 2 different Data formats which are transferred. How should i mapp and convert the different datas.

Comment: This currently lacks any useful details. Please go read [ask].

Comment: Your question is not clear enough but on quick solution from what I can understand is to count(*) the table before and after the transfer. Please provide sample data, and edit your question to be clear